# property does not exist on type 'unknown' using listenerApi.getState() in createListenerMiddleware

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

In typescript I'm trying to access current state via `getState()` provided in the listenerApi.

from the docs we know that state is 'unknown' because at the time of middleware being loaded the state is yet to be initialize.

I'm unclear how exporting the placeholder types from the middleware, as from [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#typescript-usage), helps with the call to `getState()` within the `effect`, indeed I am calling `getState()` from within the listener.

When I add the type exports the error persisits.

here is the code that fails:

```js
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: taskRetrieve,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
    // takeLeading: Starts listener on first action, ignores others until task completes
    listenerApi.unsubscribe();

    const currentTask =  listenerApi.getState().todos.tasks[0];
    
    // will do something async here later...

    listenerApi.subscribe();
  },
});
```

and the ts error:

`Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)`

I'm potentially missing something obvious here...

Comment: Did you solve this? Getting same type of error.

Comment: @jamesemanon I looked at my code (its been a while since I touched `listenerApi`). Rereading the code I removed any `.getState()` calls, and now only use `listenerApi.dispatch()`. At some point it seems I decided that `.getState()` was inappropriate for the use case - I wish I had answered here with the reason why 